# Why $∀x(P(x)→Q)$ is equivalent to $∃xP(x)→Q$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, predicate-logic, quantifiers

Given $x$ occurs free in $P$. If $x$ does not occur free in $Q$, then $∀x(P(x)→Q)$ is semantically equivalent with $∃xP(x)→Q$. How to understand this statement. And also, need an example to show that the formula will not necessarily be equivalent if $x$ does occur free in $Q$.

I guess what struggles me is I'm not quite understand what does "free" mean in this case. But it would be better to have answer for the above question.

Comment: Do you have a formal language to work with? Semantical equivalences hints towards models, which in turn require a formal language.

Comment: An occurance of a variable x is free when it is not in the scope of some "exists x" or "for all x".

Answer (score 4):

Let $\mathcal M$ a structure whatever, with domain $D$.

Two cases :

*(i)* $∃xP(x)$ is False.

Thus $∃xP(x) \to Q$ is True.

But to say that $∃xP(x)$ is False in $\mathcal M$ means that for $a \in D$ whatever, we have that $P(x)[a/x]$ is False, and thus $(P(x) \to Q)[a/x]$ is True in $\mathcal M$.

And this means in turn that $\mathcal M \vDash ∀x(P(x) \to Q)$.

*(ii)* $∃xP(x)$ is True, i.e. there is an object $a \in D$ such that $P(x)[a/x]$ is True.

Two sub-cases :

*(a)* $Q$ is False. Thus $∃xP(x) \to Q$ is False.

But $(P(x) \to Q)[a/x]$ is False for the $a \in D$ above, and thus $∀x(P(x) \to Q)$ is False in $\mathcal M$.

*(b)* $Q$ is True. Thus $∃xP(x) \to Q$ is True.

But if $Q$ is True, also $(P(x) \to Q)[a/x]$ is True, for $a \in D$ whatever.

And this means that $∀x(P(x) \to Q)$ is True in $\mathcal M$.

---

Why the condition "$x$ not *free* in $Q$" is necessary ?

First of all we have to agree on the way to define what does it mean : $\mathcal M \vDash \varphi(x)$ with $x$ free.

One convention is to consider the $\text {Closure}$ $\forall x \varphi(x)$ of the formula, i.e. :

> $\mathcal M \vDash \varphi(x) \text { iff } \mathcal M \vDash \text {Cl}(\varphi(x))$.

Consider now a simple interpretation with domain $D = \{ 0,1 \}$ and interpret both $P(x)$ and $Q(x)$ as $(x=0)$.

The LH formula is : $\forall x \ ((x=0) \to (x=0))$ while the RH formula is : $\exists x \ (x=0) \to (x=0)$.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I think I'm getting understand the logic behind these question. So what would be a proper example for the second part of the statement:  the formula will not necessarily be equivalent if $x$ does occur free in $Q$.