# I have some doubts with first order logic

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

Good morning,

This is my first time writting in this page, but I am finding trouble solving some exercises about first order logic. I know the tools I have but I am not sure how should I apply them. I attach some exercises and I hope someone could bring me some light about any of them. I need to prove those implications. (The last one says that x does not happen in phi. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HSkEJ.png)

Comment: Please, copy-paste the formulas into the text of the question.

Comment: Better to use MathJax to render the math. here you have a quick tuto https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3704651/is-%e2%88%80x%e2%88%83ylxy-and-%e2%88%83x%e2%88%80ylyx-provable-from-each-other)

Comment: As well as [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3704135/quantifier-negation-proof-with-natural-deduction)

Comment: See also [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3669834/given-%e2%88%83y-%e2%88%80x-px-y-use-the-fitch-system-to-prove-%e2%88%80x-%e2%88%83y-px-y)

Comment: And [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3032081/why-%e2%88%80xpx%e2%86%92q-is-equivalent-to-%e2%88%83xpx%e2%86%92q)